# Code behind search API results in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, rest, search-scope

I am using REST call to query a result source and fetching the results based on the search word. But it tries to absolute match the results. What I mean is if I search for `Test`. it gets me results which has Test as a keyword.

But if i search for "Test for results" does not get me results for "Test". How can we do this search.

Answer (score 2):

For "OR" searches you need the OData `$filter` parameter

See chapter: 4.5 Filter System Query Option ($filter)

of http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/

#### SharePoint endpoint and Search documentation

- URI Conventions (OData Version 2.0)
  http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/
- Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx

Search has different syntax

- SharePoint Search REST API overview
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8a4f7863-e4c1-4099-9189-a1894db36930%28office.15%29.aspx
- FAST Query Language (FQL) syntax reference
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394606.aspx

iSearch